# Listening to click on body while developing chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am new to developing extensions and would like to develop an extension that does some action when the user clicks on body for starters. It was supposed to be simple and i know we are going to use document.body.addEventListener here, but I don't know where to put it - content.js or background.js or somewhere else.

Please help as I am stuck on this thing since a long time.

Comment: Use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), but make sure to read about the [architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) first.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery:

```
$('html, body').click(function(e) {
  //do something
});
```

or Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // do the same thing differently
});
```

Then you need to get the code into the target page. You can do this one of two ways:

1) Put the code in a content script, make sure the content script is injected into all pages. So the manifest JSON must include this:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": [ "<relative path to your script here>"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
```

2) You can inject the script into each page programmatically, triggered by some other event using

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'your code here' 
  });
```

or

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "<relative path to your code here"});
```